# Is there a Dyalog equivalent to DFT function from APL/360 "1 PLOTFORMAT"?

Tags: apl, dyalog

APL newbie. Using Dyalog (18.2 on Mac) to run a function I've transcribed from Decimal Computation by Schmid a 1974 book I'm reading. The function is the source of a table in the book.

The function is

```
∇ COSANDSIN L;I;J;X;Y;Z;OUT
  OUT←0, 0, 0, X, Y, SA , PK←Z←X←J←1+I←N←SA←Y←0
 LH:A←(180÷○1)×¯3○10*-I
  →(L≤SA)/NEG
  Z←Z-Y×10*-I
  Y←Y+X×10*-I
  SA←SA+A
  →KH
 NEG:Z←Z+Y×10*-I
  Y←Y-X×10*-I
  SA←SA-A
 KH:PK←PK×1÷2○¯3○10*-I
  OUT←OUT,(N←N+1),I,J,(X←Z),Y,SA,PK
  →(I=0)/RL
  →(9≥J←J+1)/LH
  J←1
 RL:(5>I←I+1)/LH
  '   N.   I.   J.         X.         Y       SUM MU    PRODUCT K. '
  (5 0 , 5 0 , 5 0 , 12 6 , 12 6 , 12 6 , 12 6) DFT 31 7 ⍴OUT
  'COSL=X÷PK=    ';X÷PK
  'ERROR=COSL-X÷PK=';(X÷PK)-2○L×○1÷180
  'SINL=Y÷PK.    ';Y÷PK
  'ERROR=SINL-Y÷PK=';(Y÷PK)-1○L×○1÷180
∇
```

I believe I have correctly typed the function. It is accepted by Dyalog and `∇COSANDSIN[⎕]∇` correctly repeats the definition. However, when I run it, I get an undefined function `DFT`.

I believe I've found the function in an image of old ACM paper https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/585882.585894 and it appears to be a formatting function from an IBM APL/360 library called `1 PLOTFORMAT`. However, the listing for that function uses I-beam 26 which I assume is an IBM specific function: I suspect that is equivalent to the first element of `[]LC` -- according to this [APL i-beam function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656779/apl-i-beam-function)

So my question is: does Dyalog have an equivalent to the DFT function?

Final format of the function using answer from @Silas and some corrections to the function

```
∇ COSANDSIN L;I;J;X;Y;Z;OUT
  OUT←0, 0, 0, X, Y, SA , PK←Z←X←J←1+I←N←SA←Y←0
 LH:A←(180÷○1)×¯3○10*-I
  →(L≤SA)/NEG
  Z←Z-Y×10*-I
  Y←Y+X×10*-I
  SA←SA+A
  →KH
 NEG:Z←Z+Y×10*-I
  Y←Y-X×10*-I
  SA←SA-A
 KH:PK←PK×1÷2○¯3○10*-I
  OUT←OUT,(N←N+1),I,J,(X←Z),Y,SA,PK
  →(I=0)/RL
  →(9≥J←J+1)/LH
  J←1 
 RL:→(5>I←I+1)/LH
  '   N.   I.   J.         X.         Y       SUM MU    PRODUCT K. '
  5 0 5 0 5 0 12 6 12 6 12 6 12 6 ⍕ 31 7 ⍴OUT
  'COSL=X÷PK=    ',X÷PK
  'ERROR=COSL-X÷PK=',(X÷PK)-2○L×○1÷180
  'SINL=Y÷PK.    ',Y÷PK
  'ERROR=SINL-Y÷PK=',(Y÷PK)-1○L×○1÷180
∇
```

Which produces the exact same table as the original book

```
COSANDSIN 30
   N.   I.   J.         X.         Y       SUM MU    PRODUCT K. 
    0    0    0    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
    1    0    1    1.000000    1.000000   45.000000    1.414214
    2    1    1    1.100000    0.900000   39.289407    1.421267
    3    1    2    1.190000    0.790000   33.578814    1.428356
    4    1    3    1.269000    0.671000   27.868221    1.435480
    5    1    4    1.201900    0.797900   33.578814    1.442639
    6    1    5    1.281690    0.677710   27.868221    1.449835
    7    1    6    1.213919    0.805879   33.578814    1.457066
    8    1    7    1.294507    0.684487   27.868221    1.464333
    9    1    8    1.226058    0.813938   33.578814    1.471636
   10    1    9    1.307452    0.691332   27.868221    1.478976
   11    2    1    1.300539    0.704406   28.441159    1.479050
   12    2    2    1.293495    0.717412   29.014098    1.479124
   13    2    3    1.286320    0.730347   29.587037    1.479198
   14    2    4    1.279017    0.743210   30.159975    1.479272
   15    2    5    1.286449    0.730420   29.587037    1.479346
   16    2    6    1.279145    0.743284   30.159975    1.479420
   17    2    7    1.286578    0.730493   29.587037    1.479494
   18    2    8    1.279273    0.743359   30.159975    1.479568
   19    2    9    1.286706    0.730566   29.587037    1.479642
   20    3    1    1.285976    0.731853   29.644332    1.479643
   21    3    2    1.285244    0.733139   29.701628    1.479643
   22    3    3    1.284511    0.734424   29.758924    1.479644
   23    3    4    1.283776    0.735708   29.816220    1.479645
   24    3    5    1.283041    0.736992   29.873515    1.479646
   25    3    6    1.282304    0.738275   29.930811    1.479646
   26    3    7    1.281565    0.739558   29.988107    1.479647
   27    3    8    1.280826    0.740839   30.045403    1.479648
   28    3    9    1.281567    0.739558   29.988107    1.479648
   29    4    1    1.281493    0.739686   29.993837    1.479649
   30    4    2    1.281419    0.739815   29.999566    1.479649
COSL=X÷PK=     0.8659791861
ERROR=COSL-X÷PK= ¯0.0000462177248
SINL=Y÷PK.     0.5000800429
ERROR=SINL-Y÷PK= 0.00008004290462
```

Comment: Hit time limit for answering but believe DFT is ⍕

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the paper, I believe DFT is simply dyadic format or [⍕](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm) with FMT being a variant of [⎕FMT](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm)

At least your COSANDSIN function seems to work when I replace DFT with ⍕ and ; with ,

Comment: Thx Silas. 
 5 0 5 0 5 0 12 6 12 6 12 6 12 6 ⍕ 31 7 ⍴OUT
perfectly replaces
(5 0 , 5 0 , 5 0 , 12 6 , 12 6 , 12 6 , 12 6) DFT 31 7 ⍴OUT