# What is the Dyalog equivalent of the APL/360 I-beam 26?

Tags: migration, apl, dyalog, dialect

What is the best translation from APL/360 to Dyalog for I-beam 26 for example in the lines:

```
→(3 2 1 ⍴⍴X)/(DFTERR+F←0), 2 3 +⌶26
```

```
→(∧/0≤Y)/2+⌶26
```

?

(The APL\360 manual at https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/APL360ReferenceManual says

```
⌶26  Current value of line counter. In the execution
         of a defined function, this is the command
         number of the command being executed. ⌶26 can
         be used for branching. For example, →2+⌶26 is a
         branch to two commands beyond the present one.
```

)

Comment: I'll leave it for Adám to answer this, but it would not surprise me to find that there is no equivalent. If I couldn't find an answer easily, I'd just rewrite to branch to a labelled line.

Comment: Thx, Jeff! I'm v new to APL. So I get the /2+⌶26 I guess I translate that by replacing with /JUMPTWOAHEADLABEL however, →(3 2 1 ⍴⍴X)/(DFTERR+F←0), 2 3 +⌶26 I'm not sure of. Is that a jump to a label 1 after the next? So I translate it as replacing the +⌶26 with  /JUMPONEAHEADLABEL  ?

Comment: That second line amounts to "If all of the values in the numeric vector `Y` are zero or negative, jump to the second command past the current one", so if you make that line (two past the current one) say, e.g., `JUMPTARGET: `«do stuff», then you'd change the line to read `→(∧/0≤Y)/JUMPTARGET`.

Comment: Right! The first one is a little more challenging to my lack of APL!

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to analyse that one. My APL is existent, but rusty. 'swhy I figured on leaving it to Adám to answer, since he works for Dyalog... (He won't answer before Monday; it's past sunset on shabbat, and he's very Orthodox Jewish.)

Comment: Thx Jeff Gives nice deadline to play with the problem.
Ironically there appears to be a label for one of them already

 →(0=F)/3+⌶26
 J←J[;(1⌽⍳G),(G+-/W[;H])+⍳F]
 J[;G]←11
 ←DFTLP,⍴Z[;(+/W[1;⍳H-1])+⍳I]←D[1+J]
DFTEND:→L/0

Comment: Not certain (hence commenting, rather than answering) but maybe [⎕LC](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/lc.htm) ? Bit uncertain given says command, not line to jump to. `→2+⎕LC` is jump forward 2 lines

Comment: I had tried that at it was suggested in the one of the stack threads, but Dyalog says []LC is undefined when I tried it.

Comment: Ah oops. I did not use quad when I first tried it. I did this time and I no longer get an undefined. But the code I'm trying to get running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168626/is-there-a-dyalog-equivalent-to-dft-function-from-apl-360-1-plotformat/78169073#78169073 now has a rank error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `50100⌶1`

The problem with `⎕LC` is that it returns one line counter per stack frame so `2 3 +⌶26` will give a length error if the stack has more than two frames, and will give the wrong result if the stack has two frames. In contrast, `50100⌶` takes an argument which is the number of stack frames to report on (`1`).

We could also write `⊃⎕LC` (first of the line counter, assuming `⎕ML≤1`) but `50100⌶1` is more efficient.

Comment: Thx. Impressive!

Comment: @NeilBartlett Btw, `50100` comes from `LC` (Line Counter) where each letter is interpreted as a a Roman numeral, i.e. 50 100.